# Inverse mapping in dart

Tags: dart

Say that I have the following map in dart:

```
Map f = {
  0 : 0,
  1 : 1,
  2 : 0,
  3 : 1, 
  4 : 0,
  5 : 1
};
```

Is there something in dart so that you can easily work with the inverse map of the map `f`? So for example, the inverse map `f⁻¹[0]` (in math notation) should be equal to the set `0, 2, 4` in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
Map f = {
  0 : 0,
  1 : 1,
  2 : 0,
  3 : 1,
  4 : 0,
  5 : 1
};

main() {
  print(f.keys.where((k) => f[k] == 0));
  // or 
  print(new Map.fromIterable(f.values.toSet(), 
    key: (k) => k, 
    value: (v) => f.keys.where((k) => f[k] == v)));
}
```

try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9f03791e75c4bcc8c7c2)

Answer (score 9):

If values are unique then it's just:

```
Map inverse(Map f) {
 return f.map( (k, v) => MapEntry(v, k) );
}
```

it doesn't complain about duplicates, it overwrites them.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [`BiMap`](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/quiver/0.21.3/index.html#quiver/quiver-collection.BiMap) class in quiver.dart library (although it might be overkill to use a library for just this single purpose).

[Here](https://github.com/curioustechizen/dartlee/blob/14504aabbb1aa8d57052efc848b3b06ee1911048/lib/LeetTranslator.dart) is an example real-world usage of this class.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by gunter's answer:

```
Map inverse(Map f) {
  Map inverse = {};
  f.values.toSet().forEach((y) {
    inverse[y] = f.keys.where((x) => f[x] == y).toSet();
  });
  return inverse;
}
```

[DartPad demo](http://dev.dart-pad.appspot.com/aa215bae742132630caf)

Comment: Or just `var inverse = {}; f.forEach((k, v) { inverse.putIfAbsent(v, () => new Set()).add(k); }`